# react js button hide while click in button

Tags: reactjs

here is my reactjs button code how can hide while clicking in button

```
<div className='chat-bubble animated bounceInLeft' style={{display:'none'}}>
            <div><img src={giabot} alt="" className="round"/></div>
          <div className="chat-content"> {chatData.text[3]}<br/>
            <div className="btn-group">
            {
              chatData.values.map((obj, index) => {
                return (
                  <button className='button' onClick={this.buttonSubmit} key={index} value={obj}>{obj}</button>
                )
              })
            }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try to answer these questions yourself and you will have an answer: How do you hide a DOM element? How do you render UI based on DOM actions in react? If these questions don't look relevant, probably go give a read to documentations little more.

Answer (score 0):

you can do someting like this, at first set showButton field true and onClick make it false

```
buttonSubmit = ()=> {
    this.setState({ showButton: false });
},

  <div className='chat-bubble animated bounceInLeft' style={{display:'none'}}>
    <div><img src={giabot} alt="" className="round"/></div>
      <div className="chat-content"> {chatData.text[3]}<br/>
        <div className="btn-group">
        {
          chatData.values.map((obj, index) => {
            return (
              {showButton && (
              <button className='button' onClick={this.buttonSubmit} key={index} value={obj}>{obj}</button>
            )}
            )
          })
        }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
buttonSubmit = ()=> {
this.setState({ showButton: !this.state.showButton });
},

<div className='chat-bubble animated bounceInLeft' style={{display:'none'}}>
    <div><img src={giabot} alt="" className="round"/></div>
  <div className="chat-content"> {chatData.text[3]}<br/>
    <div className="btn-group">
    {
      chatData.values.map((obj, index) => {
        return (
          {showButton && (
          <button className='button' onClick={this.buttonSubmit} key={index} value={obj}>{obj}</button>
        )}
        )
      })
    }
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A small change to the above answer. You can enable and disable it onclick